# why JavaScript Find method not finding the element inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have go a varabile called checkBox which should find the input tag inside the `<td>` and an attribute to it. but the find method seems not finding the input tag. does any one knows why.

```js
$("#table-products tbody tr td").on('click', function () {
    var checkBox = $(this).find("input");
    if ($(checkBox).is(':checked')) {
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        checkBox.prop("checked",true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table-products">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Product Categorey</th>
                            <th>Product Price</th>
                            <th>Product Color</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Iphone 4</td>
                            <td>Mobiles</td>
                            <td>450</td>
                            <td>Red</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="product-checkbox" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain *what* doesn't work? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: The code above is doing exactly what you ask of it: When you try to click the checkbox, your code immediately finds it and unchecks it - you have essentially prevented the checking of that box with your code.

Comment: The find method does not finds the input tag and does not adds an attribute to it I would rather select the input class to make things work so I want to know why the find method is not working and find the input tag

Comment: @user16908948 the `.find()` method most definitely does find the element. Click *inside the table cell* but outside the checkbox and you'd see that it works.

Comment: I am using chrome and its not working there is an answer for the queation but yet not explaind why we need to use parent and not finding element via find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#table-products tbody tr td").on('click', function () {
    var checkBox = $(this).parents('tr').find("input");
    if ($(checkBox).is(':checked')) {
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        checkBox.prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the find method was not working thanks @younesBennour

Comment: find method was not working because you clicked on another td not has input

Comment: you need to return to tr and use find to find your input

Comment: yes but why I need to return to tr first can you explain yes code words I had similar code I was using just tr are but now I need to include td

Comment: when using find in tr, will search in all td includes input, but if use find in td will search only on td you clicked it
if you use $("#table-products tbody tr") without td, no need return to tr